# Jupyter Lab show monthly sales for Media and gaming department

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a DataBase server and I need to get Sales by Month for The Media and Gaming dept "55". The sales in the Data Base are weekly but I need to show total sales per month only for Dept 55 and show only the mont and year for date.

Here is what I got so far but this adds all the sales throughout out the years and shows only one date.

This is the result of my code

```
All sales
StoreID 55.0
Total Sales  105029467.5636
Date  2019-02-05
```

```
import pandas as pd
def get_sales():
    conn = create_conn()
    cursor =conn.cursor()
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
    select_query ="""SELECT dept, sum(Weekly_Sales), SalesDate
    FROM sales 
    WHERE dept IN ('55')
    GROUP BY dept;"""
    cursor.execute(select_query)
    results =cursor.fetchall()
    print("All sales: ")
    for row in results:
        print("StoreID = ", row[0], )
        print("Total Sales = ", row[1],)
        print("Date = ", row[2], "\n")
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_sales()
```

Comment: `GROUP BY dept` asks it to produce one row that summarizes every entry for that department.  If you want it grouped by month, then you need to do something like `GROUP BY YEAR(SalesDate),MONTH(SalesDate)`.